# Does GHC optimize away unused code and packages?

Tags: haskell, module, package, ghc, compiler-optimization

Let's say a big package is included to a project and only one function from the package is used, is the rest of the code optimized away when compiling the final binary?

And If a package is included, but at the end it's never used (for example it's used to import a type by another library that's never used in the end), is the whole package stripped?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [split-objs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#ghc-flag--split-objs)

Comment: If I recall correctly, it depends if the end result is statically linked or dynamically linked.... For dynamically linked - no. You have to include all of the `.so` files. For statically linked, I remember that only the relevant symbols are in the end result.

Comment: @chi The [`split-sections`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#ghc-flag--split-sections) right below seems about what Petr is thinking.

Comment: @Bakuriu technically both of you are correct. `split-sections` is replacing `split-objs` but `split-sections` is not supported yet on all platforms (Windows support will be finished by 8.2.1)